# Questions about homotopic path

Tags: algebraic-topology

Recently I am watching algebraic topology classes on youtube. When I watch the Lecture 24 which talked about homotopic path, I saw the professor show this picture and formulas: (link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dkhuzT9zxxM at time 7:23) 
[the question picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RniD4.png)

In this picture, the professor said the path $\alpha$ should be mapped to the interval t=[0,1] on x axis and the path $\beta$ should be mapped to the interval t=[0,1] which s=1. But I think the t axis is not equal to "time" right? Because H(0,s), as far as I am concerned, is the path on time 0, and the s is the actual interval we transformed to the path on our surface. So if I want to draw the path $\alpha$ and refer the t axis as "time", I should draw a vertical line not a horizontal line. Also in the rest of the video, he used the $\alpha$(t) for example: $\alpha$(t)=t to represent a path, so I am confused by these symbols.
So could anyone tell me whether I am right, or I what I understand is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $s$ variable selects the path from the family of paths.

Thus,

- For $s=0$, $H(t,0)=\alpha(t)$, so $s=0$ yields the path $\alpha$.

  For $s=1$, $H(t,1)=\beta(t)$, so $s=1$ yields the path $\beta$.

For a fixed value of $s$, the $t$ variable is the parameter for the path with the given $s$-value.

When you say

- the path $\alpha$ should be mapped to the interval t=[0,1] on x axis

that should be corrected to

- for $s=0$, as $t$ varies from $0$ to $1$, the interval $[0,1]$ is mapped to the image of $\alpha$.

Similarly, when you say

- the path $\beta$ should be mapped to the interval t=[0,1] which s=1.

that should be corrected to

- for $s=1$, as $t$ varies from $0$ to $1$, the interval $[0,1]$ is mapped to the image of $\beta$.

Also, when you say

- H(0,s), as far as I am concerned, is the path on time 0

that's not a correct understanding of the meaning of $H(0,s)$.

For each fixed $s\in[0,1]$, $H(0,s)$ and $H(1,s)$ are the initial and final points, respectively, of the path with the given $s$-value.

Based on the definition of homotopy, $H(0,s)=\alpha(0)=\beta(0)$, and $H(1,s)=\alpha(1)=\beta(1)$, so $H(0,s)$ and $H(1,s)$ are *constant* (i.e., they don't vary as $s$ varies from $0$ to $1$).

If you choose to regard $t$ as "time", then it should be regarded as time for a fixed value of $s$ (i.e., for a particular path from the family of paths).

Thus, the presenter in the video is correct:

Each horizontal line segment of the unit square maps to the image of a path from the family of paths.

Comment: Many thanks to you! I have understood what the "s" means, but I am still confused about the t variable. You know there are two intervals. The first is the one we use $\alpha$ to map it to the path on our surface, and the second is the time which is also an interval. You say that "for s=0, as t varies from 0 to 1, the interval [0,1] is mapped to the image of α." So what is the t here? I mean I should treat every point on the unit square as one point on the path or one value on the first interval?

Comment: No No No, I am sorry I did not present my confusion clearly ( Because I am a little confused now). If you treat the t as time interval, then every horizontal line may be regarded as the path along which one point moves. But if you treat the t as our initial interval, which means you treat every point on the unit square as a point on the path, then you missed the time variable. So...... I need your help!

Comment: So if you treat "s" as the variable used to select path, can I think that the utility of "s" is the same as the time? Because if you want to select the path, that means you need to select one at a specific time point. So I can treat the "s" as time. And for the "t" axis, I treat it as the initial interval. So in my view, that would make sense, because every point on the unit square means a specific point on a specific path ( which also means at a specific time)

Comment: Every point on the unit square maps to some point on the particular path with the given $s$-value.

Comment: The $t$-axis $(s=0)$ within the unit square corresponds to the initial path $\alpha$. The top segment ($s=1$) of the unit square corresponds to the path $\beta$. Each intermediate horizontal line segment of the unit square corresponds to an intermediate path in the family of paths.

Comment: OK thank you ! So that is what I mean and what I thought initially. It is kind of same to treat the change of "s" as change of time, and the change of "t" as change of the point on the initial interval ( also refer to the corresponding point on the path at "s")

Comment: Yes, $s$ could be regarded as time. At each "time" $s$, you get a path from the family of paths. And then for the path with a given $s$-value, the variable $t$ parametrizes that path (so could be regarded as "time" relative to that specific path).